# How to control default permission on copy file unix

Tags: unix, copy, file-permissions

I have executed a shell script in which I have copied a file as root user in another user as:

```
cp myFile.txt /opt/another_user/some_dir/
```

The file permissions in that user are `-rw-r--r--` but I have the replica of this machine, where I executed the same command but the permissions of file are `-rwxr-x---`.

Why this default permission is different in 2 machines. Whether we set some rules while creating the user.

Answer (score 0):

To ellaborate a bit on John3136's answer:

There's this thing called "file mode creation mask." Each shell has its own (ie. if you change it and open a new terminal, the new terminal gets the default value), and it's a chmod-type permission string which is **subtracted** from new files.

You can print yours by running `umask`:

```
$ umask
002
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

As you can see, mine subtracts the "other write" bit:

```
$ chmod 777 tmp
$ cp tmp tmp2
$ ls -l tmp2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ahhrk ahhrk 0 may 19 10:55 tmp2*
```

Here's [`umask`'s generic POSIX documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/umask.1p.html). Note that your implementation might unlikely be slightly different. On Ubuntu, I found my specific `umask` documentation in `man 1 bash`, not `man umask`. (The latter leads to [`man 2 umask`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html), which refers to the `umask()` system call, which has little to do with our purposes.)

Slightly more ellaborate example:

```
$ # remove read from user, write from group and execute from other
$ umask 421
$ cp tmp tmp3
$ ls -l tmp3
--wxr-xrw-  1 ahhrk ahhrk       0 may 19 11:03 tmp3*
```

So maybe one of your file mode creation masks is removing the execute bits.

Answer (score -1):

RTFM. Specically the `umask` FM, via `man umask`

You may also want to check what your chosen shell's manual page says about umask.